# What search algorithm fails fastest

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer, I need to find a match from a small set.  The integer will almost always **not** be in the set.  For most search algorithms, that is the worst case (taking the longest).  But for this application, search time will be dominated by how quickly the search fails.  So I want an algorithm who's best case is 'not found'.

Does such a thing exist?

The integers are far from random, being array indexes -- say 0..10k (15-bits).  The sets will contain 0..7 integers, which is few enough for a simple linear search.  But that would be worst case in almost every case.

The only thing I can think of would be a Bloom Filter.  It would work something like this:  Define F(int) = Set Bit (i AND 1Fh) (that is, a 32-bit integer with one bit set).  With each set I would store the OR'd together values of F(each element) (a 32-bit integer with max n-bits set for n elements).  The search would then be IF (F(i) AND F(set))>0 then perform linear search.

Thus the search would never be performed unless at least one set element had the same low 5-bits as the test integer i.  A second test could be added based on the next lowest 5-bits.

Better ideas anyone?

Comment: A set of up to 7 16-bit integers will fit neatly into a single cache line, so the naïve approach is probably already optimal in terms of memory access efficiency. What leads you to believe that a linear search is worth optimizing away?

Comment: In principle a bloom filter could be a good approach, but with only 7 elements, you're going to have a hard time beating linear search.  Your suggested hash is not very good (think about how many bits are expected to be set when you have 4 elements).  If SSE instructions are in play, you might be able to do the comparisons in one instruction with VCMPPS.

Comment: @willglynn, Profiling indicates this is a hot spot.  This code is inside a triple loop, and is part of an optimization to skip most inner cases.  The data structures involved are designed with cache-efficiency in mind.  I was thinking about how to order the set elements when it occurred to me to that it was probably pointless because I needed to examine the entire set in most cases.  Thus the question.

Comment: @rlibby; Agreed, linear search will be hard to beat.  Since these integers are consecutive, the 5-LSB will be evenly distributed.  Yes, I thought about bit count.  In the native integer I'll have a 32-bit filter, and I want most of them to remain 0.   Filters #2 & 3 could each be the next 5 bits.  In 3 tests I could know for certain if the test integer was present -- but not know which one.  But on average, a linear search will find the exact answer in just a number of compares equal to the average set occupancy.

Comment: I'd figure that testing for existence within a set is nearly optimal already, so I'd focus on finding ways to eliminate this search instead of making it faster. That might be a bloom filter over multiple sets, but without knowing more about the outer loops, it's hard to say. Could you describe the wider problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest algorithm I can imagine, which would succeed or fail immediately, is a huge array 0..MaxInt of Boolean, all False except True at Array[Set Member].  Search would be a simple array lookup:

```
Found = Array[Test]
```

But the memory footprint is absurd.  A common optimization is a Hash Array.

As a test, I have implemented a Perfect Hash using bits of the Set Members.  The function PHash(int) returns an integer 0..15 which is the array index where the match will be found **if one exists**.  The search is then:

```
IF Array[PHash(Test)] = Test 
  THEN Found at Index PHash(Test) 
  ELSE Not Found
```

It will probably surprise no one that profiling shows this to be slower than a linear search.
(sigh)

Of course, no single Hash can reduce 15-bit integers to distinct 4-bit integers.  I use many different hash functions.  To produce the Set, I find which function produces distinct 4-bit hashes for that Set, then store the Set as the Hash Function Pointer plus a 16 element Array.  Each Array element is either X or one Set Member, where X is not in the set range.  (Failure to find a Perfect Hash would throw an exception, which has not yet happened.)  None of this overhead matters in profiling as it is done once at program start.

To find a Test integer in a Set, I call Set.HashFunction(Test), then compare Test to that Set.Array Element.  That final compare is the same as each step of a linear search.  To be faster, the Hash Function must be faster than the remaining compares of the linear search.  So this **could** be a faster algorithm, but only for large enough set sizes.

I have not experimented to find that set size.  Anyway it would depend upon the speed of each hash function.

Comment: What is the wider context? I maintain that the only way to evaluate this faster than a single cache line fill will be to expand the problem scope. Coalescing or selectively eliminating these innermost tests may be possible. Even if not, the outer loop might warrant explicit prefetching of the data that will be needed N iterations in the future -- assuming the logic is such that the CPU isn't able to guess what to prefetch already. Without more information, this is all just speculation.